# CSS Background image animation wont work

Tags: image, css, animation, background

im trying to do a css background animation with the Body tag. Here's the code

```
body
{
animation-name:mymove;
animation-duration:5s;
animation-direction:alternate;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-name:mymove;
-webkit-animation-duration:5s;
-webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
@keyframes mymove
{
from {background-image:url('Space.png');}
to {background:blue;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove
{
from {background-image:url('Space.png');}
to {background:blue;}
}
```

But when i use it the background just fades from white to blue. Is there a reason why the image wont display? And by the way the image directory is correct and works if i just set it as the background image.

Comment: And heres the html  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Use the `edit` button to add more content to the question. This way you can format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background image isn't a property that can be animated - you can't tween the property. Thus you cant use it with keyframe animations. Instead try this code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body
{background:url('Space.png');}

#frame
{
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%; /* or the height of webpage is px */
width: 100%; /* or the width of webpage is px */
animation-name:mymove;
animation-duration:5s;
animation-direction:alternate;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-name:mymove;
-webkit-animation-duration:5s;
-webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
@keyframes mymove
{
from {background:transparent;}
to {background:blue;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove
{
from {background:transparent;}
to {background:blue;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="frame">
<--- Webpage contents --->
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to say from one image to another? Yes it can.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Background images CAN be animated: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/background-animation-css.php